# In App purchase and paypal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have to create an application in which the user are of two types : basic and premium.
Now the problem in that a user can change its type using website and from iPhone application as well.

> So tell me is there any issue if we allow user to change the user type
>   either from application or from website i.e. using Paypal.

As per the guidelines of apple we can not unlock any feature in the application using any other mode except InApp purchase.

So please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As you already discovered:

> As per the guidelines of apple we can not unlock any feature in the application using any other mode except InApp purchase.

Which means that you cannot let users change their type from any other source, the reason is simple: Apple gets part of the income from every in app purchase, i.e. you need to play by the rules and use *only* their app store network for selling any type of content to the user.

Comment: But linkden is doing the same i think.There are two type of account : basic and premium. I yet found no payment method in any of the application i.e iOS and android.So it clearly means that LinkedIn is using website for payment.

Comment: You're not allowed to take payment from within the app. But you can take payment on your website.